# Module <rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest in the transform option was not found

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, babel-jest

I got an error and I need your help. Thank for watching this question.

My situation: I am configuring Drone CI tool for my project and I get this when I run **unit test on drone.yml**.

```
Validation Error:

  Module <rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest in the transform option was not found.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

Here is my `jest.conf.js`

```
transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    ".*\\.vue$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
  },
```

What I have tried:

1. Remove `<rootDir>/node_modules/`. But I got an another error `Module vue-jest in the transform option was not found.`. So I think it is not the right solution

Comment: did get a fix? How was this fixed?

Comment: @Jayan Yup. I found a solution. But, It is too long from now and I moved to new company. So I don't remember  it now. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

Take a note that `vue-jest` is currently (2022) distributed in [3 concurrent packages](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest):

- `vue-jest`
- `@vue/vue2-jest`
- `@vue/vue3-jest`

In my case I've upgraded some dependencies and I had to switch from `vue-jest` to `@vue/vue3-jest`.

So my `jest.config.js` has to change accordingly:

```js
module.exports = {
...
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install --save-dev vue-jest
```

and rerun your test

Comment: I keep getting the same issue even though the package is in the node_modules folder